# Best way to deal with multiple layouts in symfony

Tags: php, symfony1

Hey folks. I'm looking for the best way to do something simple in symfony.

Basically, I have a module in which all the pages will contain the same header and footer. That module also shares the same general layout as the other modules.

I'm just wondering, should I create one file and have my content pages called up as partials or should all files have their own content and somehow call the two other templates.

I made a quick example of my setup: http://grab.by/3Riy

Hopefully, it'll help understand what I'm trying to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with partials instead.

indexSuccess.php

```
<?php include_partial("header"); ?>
Content
<?php include_partial("footer"); ?>
```

This way, it still work with my original layout.php as well.

Comment: If you're able to pass all needed variables to the partials from all the actions in the module in question (or don't need to pass anything), I'd also go with partials. I think Crozin's solution is fine too but would require you to always define the slot or use a default, which may or may not be appropriate across all your modules, depending on the overall structure of the site.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this that way:

1. Create `layout.php` file that will contain:

   1. Website header
   2. [include_slot](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/07-Inside-the-View-Layer#chapter_07_sub_slots) (for Module header)
   3. `echo $sf_content` (module template/content)
   4. include_slot (for Module footer)
   5. Website footer
2. In module's templates you define slots for module header and footer.